# UIPanGestureRecognizer triggers too many times

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIPanGestureRecognizer that is detecting far too many times for my liking. I need to have a counter and count 3 completed gestures. each time I pan with my finger in the recognizer spot, it triggers 3 or 4 times. has even triggered 5.

How can a recognizer be set to detect less, or what causes it to detect so many times?

I would like 3 single detections in a row. currently that could cause anything from 9 to 15 calls to the function.

Comment: Gestures can be either *discrete* or *continuous*. A discrete gesture, such as a double tap, occurs once in a multi-touch sequence and results in a single action sent. However, a continuous gesture such as a pan gesture, results in an action message sent for each incremental change until the multi-touch sequence concludes. Within the action method you can check whether the `state` property of the gesture recognizer is set to `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, which means that the gesture has been completed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use state property of your recognizer. Call your function if state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.